# DECRBY in Redis not working in Python code

Tags: python-2.7, redis

I am using redis in my Python code to store keys, however there the Python code wasn't running as it was supposed to. I haven't found any errors in my code, so I started turning things into comments and I found that the redis command DECRBY doesn't seem to work.

I have tried all the various commands such as INCR, INCRBY, and DECR and those work. But DECRBY isn't acting as expected (even though it is the same syntax as INCRBY and that works).

```
elif (text == "test1"):
    r.incr(count)
    send_message(sender_id, r.get(count))
elif (text == "test2"):
    r.incrby(count,10)
    send_message(sender_id, r.get(count))
elif (text == "test3"):
    r.decr(count)
    send_message(sender_id, r.get(count))
elif (text == "test4"):
    r.decrby(count,10)
    send_message(sender_id, r.get(count))
```

My program sends a message through Facebook regarding the result. I have the code in a try statement and an exception that sends a message that says "Exception".

I have initialized the count to 8, and as you can see here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1NI2.jpg .

It throws the exception for test4 which is DECRBY.

I have tried the commands in the Redis CLI, and DECRBY works in the command line, but not when from the python program.

The workaround I am using right now is the INCRBY method by the negative of the value I want to decrease.

Is there a reason why the DECRBY wouldn't work? I can't figure out why r.incrby works, but changing it to r.decrby leaving everything else constant doesn't. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: "It throws the exception for test4 which is DECRBY." What is the exception?

Comment: @chris, I have try except code, I just wrote wrote a line under except: to send message with the text "Exception". I am hosting on heroku, and the logs don't show any errors through that. Just shows sending message "Exception". I will try doing it without the try except and have it intentionally break to see what occurs.

Comment: @chris, when I took out the try and except line and ran it, I got this:

2019-02-12T23:36:59.601330+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 129, in webhook

2019-02-12T23:36:59.601332+00:00 app[web.1]: r.decrby(count,10)

2019-02-12T23:36:59.601334+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'Redis' object has no attribute 'decrby'

Comment: This is hard to diagnose precisely without knowing which Redis connection library you're using or having a minimal, complete, verifiable example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some tips). Glad to take another look if you can flesh this out a bit more.

Comment: In requirements.txt, I have redis==2.10.6